# Is it possible to customize email template for UserManagement.initSelfRegistration()?

Tags: community, self-registration

I am using [UserManagement.initSelfRegistration()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_UserManagement.htm) to send an email with a verification code. I am wondering how can I customize an email that is sent during this process? I found one template in Classic Email Templates, but it seems that Salesforce uses another template. After I customized the "Communities: One-Time Password Email" email template, I still received the system email.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try going to Setup > All Communities, and then:

1. Click "Workspaces" next to the Community you want to modify the email template for
   [image]
2. Go to "Administration"
   [image]
3. Explicitly select the template you want to use for One-Time Password
   [image]

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. The email I am getting has subject "Sandbox: Verify your new account in <community name>" while the subject from the Communities: One-Time Password Email template is "Verify your identity in {!Community_Name}"

Comment: Yeah, there’s no mention to customizing the email template for the self verification challenge in the doc for UserManagement class (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_UserManagement.htm). I guess it is not supported at the time.

Comment: @Eduard did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @Jeff, unfortunately no