# How to Update Verbiage on Outbound Passwordless Community Registration and Verification

Tags: community, email, login, sms

How do I edit the verbiage that is sent from the following Apex Methods? **Is this possible?**

*method = SMS or EMAIL*

1. New Community User: UserManagement.initSelfRegistration(method, user)
2. Existing Community User: UserManagement.initPasswordlessLogin(user.Id, method)

EMAIL Example (how do I update this verbiage?):

[image: outbound email example]

SMS Example (how do I update this verbiage?):

[image: outbound sms example]

Any feedback is appreciated. **Does Salesforce HAVE documentation that states this is NOT POSSIBLE?** I'm having trouble finding documentation for either stating this is possible, or impossible. I found [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289200/is-it-possible-to-customize-email-template-for-usermanagement-initselfregistrati) question referring to EMAIL which states it's impossible... but that was 2 years ago.

Thank you.

====================================================

I did notice [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_UserManagement.htm) documentation says:

> **initPasswordlessLogin(userId, method):**
> Use this method along with its paired verifyPasswordlessLogin to
> customize the login experience with your own Visualforce Login and
> Verify pages. Invoke initPasswordlessLogin from the Login page where
> the user enters an email address or phone number.

But this is only what the user experiences on the webpage to initiate the SEND, not the verbiage that is sent to them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Resolution:**

**Email Verbiage is updated:** Community > Workspaces > Administration > Email > add your custom Email Template with {!verification_code} somewhere sprinkled in to **One-Time Password**. ([related question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/289200/is-it-possible-to-customize-email-template-for-usermanagement-initselfregistrati)) ([Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_one_time_password_email.htm&type=5))

**SMS Verbiage is updated:** you **CANNOT** update this at this time. To my understanding this is in Salesforce backlog, but not a priority, and may or may not ever happen.